# JavaFX doesn't find my resource in the resources folder

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx

(The answer given to the suggested Stack question **didn't** help me reach anything, as I've already imported the resources based on those rules).

I've built a JavaFX Gradle project with IntelliJ.

I'm trying to access a `users.xml` file, located in my project's **resources** folder. This is my project's structure:

[image]

In my `HelloController.java` class, I'm trying to access the resource in the following method:

```
protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
            String path = getClass().getResource("users.xml").toExternalForm();
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            TypeReference<List<User>> typeReference= new TypeReference<List<User>>() {};
            List<User> users = mapper.readValue(inputStream, typeReference);

            for (User u: users) {
                System.out.println(u.getUsername() + "\n" + u.getPassword() + "\n");
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The problem is that I receive an error telling me that the file path is invalid:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path`

At that point, what I tried to do was printing the `path` variable and this was the output:

`jar:file:///E:/git/demo/build/libs/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/example/demo/users.xml`

As you can see, my program is looking in some sort of **build/libs** folder (inside the jar?) for my resource, instead of looking at the **build/resources** folder, where my `.xml` file was copied.

[image]

What may be the problem?

Comment: _I've already imported the resources based on those rules_ no, you didn't - you are trying to access the resource with file system api and that's __wrong__ as the duplicate clearly points out ;)

Comment: As already pointed out, it is a resource not a file.  If you want it as a Stream, then call [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).  If you still have issues refer to troubleshooting in the duplicate.  Your misunderstanding may be in thinking the resource at runtime would be picked up from your build source resource folder rather than inside your built and deployed package (jar file), which is what actually happens.